# How to Render 2D Sprites with Deferred Shading

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, deferred-rendering

with deferred shading you have several buffers to hold information like depth, normal and so on.

In the final stage you just need to "combine" them and process lighting, but how is it done, when you need to render 2D sprites for GUI?

Do you need to fallback on forward rendering for that? Or do I have to use a separate buffer for that?

Also, what would I need to implement deferred rendering on a existing forward renderer? Does it replace the code or does it build on it, so, that I only need more buffers and other shaders? (because I still need the forward renderer for mobile devices)

Comment: Note: Stack Overflow doesn't use HTML tags like `<p>` and `<br>`. See the appropriate help page for SO formatting.

Comment: In the preview of the post it seemed like <p> and <br> worked and that was always the way I formatted the text here, so I'm now confused.

Comment: and the help page for formatting says I can use HTML tags like <p> and <br>

Answer (score 1):

You simply render your 2D elements after you have done the shading.

And no, I can't really see how it would make sense to implement deferred rendering "on an existing forward renderer", since they do things in such very different ways.

Comment: With render them after the shading, you mean I render them in deferred rendering ways so that I need to save the normals and so on from the sprites? 

Or in forward renderer way? 
For things like that I would need to keep the forward renderer again, why I was asking whats so different on a deferred renderer besides the buffer setup and shading..

Comment: @Pillum: You just draw them. There's really nothing special about this. OpenGL is not a scene graph and you can switch how you do things inbetween. If your deferred shader keeps the depth buffer intact you could even do some forward rendering afterwards.